# Making hunger bar invisible in vanilla Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there anyway that I can make the hunger bar **invisible** in **vanilla** Minecraft? I came up with a method that would involve the player riding a boat and still being able to jump and move at normal speeds, but that didn't seem like it would work. Is there anyway I can do what I am asking in **vanilla** Minecraft?

Comment: Possibly with a resource pack?

Comment: If your difficulty is set to peaceful, the hunger bar is invisible (because there is no hunger in peaceful).
Not sure if this will solve your problem though - why do you want the hunger bar to be invisible?

Comment: @Johonn the hunger bar isn't invisible in survival, just doesn't go down.

Comment: Ahh yeah you're right, now that you mention it.

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want to hide the hunger bar?

Comment: @musicwithoutpaper I am making a beta-themed survival map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As fredley said, you can do this using resource packs. Please notice that this will make them **invisible**, like you asked for, but you will still loose hunger (and eventually die depending on difficulty).

You can download it [here](http://ineentho.com/no-hunger-bar.zip), or read on to make one yourself.

Resource packs are basically zip files containing resources to override from vanilla minecraft packaged together.

First you will have to create a pack.mcmeta for your resource pack containing some basic information about your pack:

**pack.mcmeta**

```
{
  "pack": {
    "pack_format": 1,
    "description": "No hearts"
  }
}
```

Then it is just a matter of copying files from the vanilla .jar file and modifying the image as required. In our case we need textures/gui/icons.png which contains hearts, hunger bar, air bubbles etc. Just remove the the hunger bar in photoshop/paint.net or any other editing program that supports transparency (**not** MS paint).

Finally zip everything together, the resulting zip file should look like this:

```
no-hunger-bar.zip:
│   pack.mcmeta
│
└───assets
    └───minecraft
        └───textures
            └───gui
                    icons.png
```

To install a resource pack, just drag the the zip file into `%appdata%/resourcepacks` (windows).

Comment: don't worry, I made a beta themed survival map, so the hunger bar stays at a constant level to make sure that the player doesn't starve.

Comment: I also decided to replace the hunger bar with the armor bar, do it would be even more like beta minecraft.

Comment: Okey, problem with that is your new "armor bar" still functions like the hunger bar, I would be totally confused playing with that pack

Comment: I know that it would still function like the hunger bar, it's just for asthetic purposes.

Comment: Okey, that's up to you then I guess